# Suppose that $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$. If $t = \frac{p - 1}{2}$ , prove that $2^t \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Suppose that $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$. If $t = \frac{p - 1}{2}$ , prove that $$2^t \equiv 1 \pmod p.$$

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Well, $2^{p-1} \equiv 1$ mod $p$ by Fermat's little theorem, so $2^t$ is congruent to either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: If $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then $(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0$, so $p$, being prime, divides either $x-1$ or $x+1$.  That's the same as saying that $x$ is congruent to $\pm 1$.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand why that is related to this problem.

Comment: I haven't solved this problem yet, but I'm just saying that whatever $2^t$ is modulo $p$, you can narrow it down to two possibilities: what you want, and $-1$.

Comment: Just a couple of hours ago I answered a question of related nature that answers this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990937/density-of-primes-such-that-2-has-odd-order

Comment: I see, so the problem really was harder than I thought.  It comes from a special case of quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously $p$ is odd.

It is well known that $$\left(\dfrac 2p\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}$$ where $\left(\dfrac ap\right)$ is the Legendre's symbol.

On the other hand $$p=8m+7\Rightarrow p^2-1=64m^2+112m+48\Rightarrow\frac{p^2-1}{8}=8m^2+14m+6\in 2\Bbb Z$$

It follows (*because $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ is even*) $$\left(\dfrac 2p\right)= 1$$ which means that $2$ is a square modulo $p$.

Thus $$\left(2\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ denote a primitive $8$th root of unity in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$.
The element $y=\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ verifies $y^2=2$ for $y^4=-1$ hence $\alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}=0$.
Consequently, $2^{(p-1)/2}=y^{p-1}$.
Note also that $y^p=\alpha^p+\alpha^{-p}$.
If $p\equiv -1\pmod 8$ then $y^p=y$, hence $2^{(p-1)/2}=y^{p-1}=1$.